# $.Ajax without "_" querystring parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using the $.ajax method to dynamically include plugin script files, unfortunately since this entire project is hosted in Dynamics CRM 2011, no querystring parameters can be passed to this request without rubbing CRM up the wrong way.

So executing the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: includeUrl, // == "Templates.js"
    dataType: "script",
    success: function (includedFile) {
        window.Includes.push(includedFile);
    }
});
```

will return `500 - Internal Server Error` looking at the firebug console I have requested the following URL:

```
http://server:5555/Organisation/WebResources/grid_/Templates.js?_=1366828753001
```

which has got this `_=1366828753001` parameter appended by the $.Ajax method.. CRM doesn't like this very much.. I ask this knowing I'm probably between a rock and a hard place but is there any way to call $.ajax forcing it not to append this ID into the querystring?

Full error from CRM:

```
<description>CRM Parameter Filter - Invalid parameter '_=1366828753001' in Request.QueryString on page /Organisation/Handlers/WebResource.ashx
The raw request was 'GET /Organisation/WebResources/grid_/Templates.js?_=1366828753001' called from http://server:5555/Organisation/WebResources/grid_/EditableGrid.htm.</description>
```

Comment: `type:'post'`.........??

Comment: better use `$.getScript();`

Comment: @Jai: I am using `$.getScript();` really :p, but I know it uses `$.ajax();` behind the scenes so I changed my code around to ask the Q more generically.. I'm glad I did because `$.getScript();` doesn't support disabling caching per-request so I've stuck to `$.ajax();` and now I'm just calling `eval(includedFile);` in the success handler.

Comment: @MohammadAdil: you're right! making a post request should workaround my issue as this disables caching. However it's best practice to GET AJAX requests (except with sensitive form data) for the miniscule performance gain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set `cache: true` as a parameter of your $.ajax() call

That query string appended by jQuery to prevent caching of the resource being requested.

Comment: I will add, that you are probably defaulting to a GET, you will want to set `type: 'POST'` also if you want to call POST

Comment: you actually want to set it to true to prevent the querystring addition

Comment: nice one, without the guff you would've fixed my issue before I even had a chance to refresh my screen :p, will accept when timer runs out.

Comment: Glad it got you sorted out :)